# C programming: Freeing nested multidimensional arrays inside structs

Tags: c, memory, struct, malloc, free

EDIT: I'm closing this question due to poor formulation as suggested by coderredoc.

I had a problem with a free function where I mistakenly put the address of a location an argument.

```
    void freeMemory(Stack stp, int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        free(&(stp.signals[n].intervals));
    }
    free(stp.signals);

}
```

This is the correct code (look below for more info)

```
    void freeMemory(Stack stp, int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        free(stp.signals[n].intervals);
    }
    free(stp.signals);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always remember one thing, you will pass to `free` whatever you have allocated using `malloc` and it's friends.

Here you have passed `free(&(stp.signals[i].intervals));` why do you pass the address of `stp.signals[i].intervals` it's `stp.signals[i].intervals` which contains the allocated chunk's address. (the starting address of the memory chunk that was just created using `*alloc`) So `free(stp.signals[i].intervals)`
is the correct way to free it.

To be precise, what you have done here is undefined behavior.

From standard [7.22.3.3p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.3p2)

> The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. ***Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function***, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, ***the behavior is undefined***.